# Convert jsonb column to multiple columns in postgreSQL without knowing what was the key inside jsonb column

Tags: postgresql

How to convert JSONB column into multiple column when I dont know the fixed keys inside JSONb column in postgreSQL.

For example, Imagine I have three rows with different set of keys inside **columnJson** column as below

**rowID**         **columnjson**

row 1     {"a":21,"b":90}

row 2      {"a":46,"b":12, "c": 754}

row 3      {"a":19}

I want to fetch the **columnjson** as 3 columns like below

[image]

Can anyone help on this to achive it.

Comment: With dynamic SQL/prepared statement this should be achievable

Comment: What good is that result table if you don't know the columns?

Comment: Hey Bergi, We are generating an API that will give you response HTML string with rows and column in table to get Data as table in MS Excel (Data from Web). For this case we don't want to determine columns as fixed.

Comment: Handling in such a way only Lukasz

Comment: isn't it possible by using case when?

Answer (score 0):

All columns of a query must be known before the query is started. So you can't have a query that returns a different number of columns each time you run it.

But given your sample data, the following returns your expected result:

```
select row_id, 
       column_json ->> 'a' as a,
       column_json ->> 'b' as b,
       column_json ->> 'c' as c
from the_table
```

Comment: I know this answer already before posting it. But thought of checking any luck will pull data like what I expected. Anyway Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name :-)